# How to correctly name and access element IDs loaded with Repeaters?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating a drag and drop schedule interface. Users can drag items into their schedule from the tab lists on the right. I use a repeater to load crews from an SQL Server. I'm currently using a lot of EVALs to set element IDs. I'm wondering if this is good practice, or if there is a better way to set IDs?

The next step in my development is loading schedule items from a table into each day by crew, but I want to set up and understand IDs before I move on. After that, I will attempt to fire an INSERT INTO or UPDATE on a successful drop event (example: UPDATE scheduleItems SET content = card text WHERE CrewID = xx AND date = xx ). Which is why I assume my IDs need to be in order.

I'm very new to ASP.NET Web Forms development, so if my methods are way off let me know!

Here is my crew repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CrewRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="Crew<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="row">
            <div class="board-layout">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="board-text">
                        Crew ID: <%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>
                        <div id='CrewList<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>' class="crew-board-list">
                            <div id='Crew<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>Employees' class="cardEmployee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DetailsModal" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                                <p><%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("Members"))%></p>
                            </div>
                            <div id='Crew<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>Equipment' class="cardEquipment">
                                <p><%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("Vehicles"))%></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="BoardList<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-lists">

                    <div id="Sun<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-list" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <%-- load schedule items here --%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Mon<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-list" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <%-- load schedule items here --%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Tue<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-list" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <%-- load schedule items here --%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Wed<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-list" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <%-- load schedule items here --%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Thu<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-list" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <%-- load schedule items here --%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Fri<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-list" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <%-- load schedule items here --%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Sat<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("CrewID"))%>" class="board-list" ondrop="dropIt(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <%-- load schedule items here --%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My repeater for the job list:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="JobRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id='cardJob<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("Job"))%>' class="card" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
            <%--<asp:Label ID='lblJob' runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("Job")) + " - " + string.Format("{0}", Eval("Description"))%>' />--%>
            <p><%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("Job")) + " - " + string.Format("{0}", Eval("Description"))%></p>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My drag and drop JavaScript:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function dropIt(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let sourceId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    let sourceIdEl = document.getElementById(sourceId);
    let sourceIdParentEl = sourceIdEl.parentElement;
    let targetEl = document.getElementById(ev.target.id)
    let targetParentEl = targetEl.parentElement;

    if (targetParentEl.id !== sourceIdParentEl.id) {
        if (targetEl.className === sourceIdEl.className) {
            targetParentEl.appendChild(sourceIdEl);
        } else {
            targetEl.appendChild(sourceIdEl);
        }
    } else {
        let holder = targetEl;
        let holderText = holder.textContent;
        targetEl.textContent = sourceIdEl.textContent;
        sourceIdEl.textContent = holderText;
        holderText = '';
    }
}
```

My interface for reference:

[image: Schedule Interface]

Comment: What exactly do you want to understand regarding IDs? Do you want to understand how to make all the ids unique than the others?

Comment: @JamshaidKamran Yes, but also is settings IDs like this in general good practice? Will I run into issues when trying to load/save schedule items because of my IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Technically, `Repeater` Control will manage the ids by itself and if you try to concatenate more unique ids to make it extra unique, that would be an overhead on the issue that is already resolved.

See if you have a simple `Repeater` control like this with 5 items in it, I will use a simplified `Repeater` to explain it:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" draggable="true" id="mySampleDiv"></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then, it will manage the divs in this way, the `html` would be like this:

```
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_0"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_1"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_2"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_3"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_4"></div>
```

In the `id` attribute of every `runat="server"` div, it has three parts of the id to make it unique,

- Parent's ID
- ID of the control
- And the Item Index

Which means, this issue, that you are working on to concatenate the ids would be an overhead as it is always going to be unique.

Now, the issue with getting the crew id from the element in `jquery`/`javascript` is pretty easy if we use the `data-` attribute, as I suppose this information is not so sensitive.

Do something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" draggable="true" id="mySampleDiv" class="mydiv" data-crewid='<%# Eval("CrewId") %>'></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the `html` generated with `data-crewid` attribute will be something like this:

```
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_0" data-crewid="1000"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_1" data-crewid="1001"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_2" data-crewid="1002"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_3" data-crewid="1003"></div>
<div draggable="true" id="MyRepeater_mySampleDiv_4" data-crewid="1004"></div>
```

This way, you don't need to manage the ids of the element as your main concern is with getting the `crewid` when the specific element is being *dragged* or *dropped*.

And in `jquery`, you can get it like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.mydiv').on('dragstart', function(){
            var crewId = $(this).attr('data-crewid');
            // do something with the crewId
        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice, I have bound the event with the class instead of with the id, which then, is getting back the crewid from the `data-` attribute.

So far, it is clear that the ids of the divs are not important in my case, as I only need the crewid *(your scenario could be different)* or whatever id it is being set, So, instead concatenating and then splitting the ids to get the crewid, I am storing the ids in a `data-` attribute. Which will work fine to store the ids that you have.

Read this for details regarding `data-` attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

---

**UPDATE**

And if you want to get the item index from the repeater in `jquery`, you can also save that in another `data-` attribute like this:

```
data-itemindex='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about `data-` attributes, and they seem like a WAY better way to store/access CrewIDs. This will make things much easier, cheers!

Comment: I came here for something but learned something new idea. There is no specific place or time to learn. Thanks